# Powershell - remove characters after specific string in a file

Tags: powershell

I have a file which contains the following lines. I would like to remove 13 first characters on each lines which contains the string PCARTE

```
PCARTE 14/04 PAYMENTS
D17/04/2023
T-7.90
PCARTE 14/04 PAYMENTS 
D17/04/2023
T-7.13
PCARTE 14/04 PAYMENTS 
D17/04/2023
T-42.63
PCARTE 15/04 Pahe 
D15/04/2023
T-121.89
PCARTE 14/04 NY
D15/04/2023
T-11.75
PCARTE 14/04 CHE*
```

Result I would like to have :

```
PAYMENTS
D17/04/2023
T-7.90
PAYMENTS 
D17/04/2023
T-7.13
PAYMENTS 
D17/04/2023
T-42.63
Pahe 
D15/04/2023
T-121.89
NY
D15/04/2023
T-11.75
CHE*
```

I found this script but I don't know how to write the new result

```
$file = Get-Content "C:\Users\TEST\Downloads\TEST.txt"
$regex = "PCARTE *"
foreach($line in $file) {
    #$line
    if($line -like $regex)
        {
        $line.Remove(0,13)
        }
}
```

Thank you very much for your help

Answer (score 2):

You can use the [`Switch`](https://learn.microsoft.com/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_switch) statement for this:

Specific to your definition (using `-wildcard`):

```
Switch -File .\Test.txt -wildcard { 'PCARTE *' { $_.SubString(13) } Default { $_ } }
```

Or stricter (using `-regex`):

```
Switch -File .\Test.txt -regex { '^(PCARTE\s\d\d\/\d\d\s)?(.*)$' { $Matches[2] } }
```

```
PAYMENTS
D17/04/2023
T-7.90
PAYMENTS
D17/04/2023
T-7.13
PAYMENTS
D17/04/2023
T-42.63
Pahe
D15/04/2023
T-121.89
NY
D15/04/2023
T-11.75
CHE*
```

Comment: It works perfectly thank you very mich for your quick answer and your help

Answer (score 1):

What you need is [Set-Content](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.management/set-content?view=powershell-7.3):

```
$regex = "PCARTE [0-9][0-9]/[0-9][0-9] "
(Get-Content -Path  C:\Users\TEST\Downloads\TEST.txt) -replace $regex, '' | Set-Content -Path  C:\Users\TEST\Downloads\TEST.txt
```

Comment: It works perfectly thank you very mich for your quick answer and your help